# Laravel5: QueryException while writing data to related database table. Error: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just created a `categories` table and related it to `articles` table.

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

I also created a category selection field with name 'category_id' in the 'Create Article' form. Now while trying to create a new article, after I hit the submit button, I get the following error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 725: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`laratry`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT
>   `articles_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES
>   `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `body`,
>   `published_at`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (This is
>   a test article, This is yet another test article for trying to find
>   what the error is., 2016-08-15 16:11:53, 1, 2016-08-15 16:11:53,
>   2016-08-15 16:11:53))

If I **print_r( $request->all() )**,

```
Array ( 
    [_token] => E4fWVTpf2T5y23uOnaA0EK1hHyi2hYvkJZa99V3G 
    [title] => This is a test article 
    [body] => This is yet another test article for trying to find what the error is. 
    [category_id] => 1 
    [published_at] => 2016-08-15
    [tag_list] => Array ( [0] => 1 )
)
```

My Controller's store method for article:

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());
        flash()->success('Your article has been created.');
        return redirect('articles');
    }
}
```

My Models:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','body','published_at','user_id'];

    protected $dates = ['published_at','created_at'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

--

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','slug'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the category_id. 
**Change**

```
protected $fillable = ['title','body','published_at','user_id'];
```

**To**

```
protected $fillable = ['title','body','published_at','user_id', 'category_id'];
```

Comment: This looks correct...but always worth explaining it a little for the user asking ;)